# Test Class for Invocable Class

Tags: unit-test, invocable-method

Please help, had been trying but I always get 0% code coverage, I need a test class for the `Invocable` method below (Please note that the class is called being called from a flow which is triggered by a button), thanks in advance:

```java
public class CMZoomUpdater{
@InvocableMethod(label='CMZoomUpdater')   
    public static void cmzuM(List<String> campL){

        System.debug('g ' + campL[0]);      

        List<CampaignMember> deleteL = new List<CampaignMember>();

        List<CampaignMember> idLMember = new List<CampaignMember>();

        List<CampaignMember> memberL = [SELECT Id, Status, CampaignId, ContactId, Zoom_Reg_Link__c FROM CampaignMember WHERE CampaignId = :campL[0] AND Zoom_Reg_Link__c = NULL];

        for(CampaignMember memberF : memberL){

            idLMember.add(new CampaignMember (ContactId = memberF.ContactId, Status = memberF.Status, CampaignId = memberF.CampaignId));

            deleteL.add(new CampaignMember(Id = memberF.Id));


        }
            System.debug('deleteL count is ' + deleteL.size());
            delete deleteL; 
        System.debug('idLMember count is ' + idLMember.size());
        insert idLMember;
//        System.debug('idLMember count is ' + idLMember.size());

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the test code you have already written, as you might have made a simple mistake.

Comment: Invocable methods are tested more or less like any other Apex class: generate test data, call the function, assert results. I've linked our standard resources on how to build test classes above.